# Symfony4 Inject env variable and autowire error "Cannot autowire service"

Tags: autowired, symfony4

I'm trying to create a service who receive two parameters defined in .env file.

Symfony throws the next error:

> Cannot autowire service
>   "App\Modules\Sales\Infrastructure\Persistence\Http\HttpSalesRepository":
>   argument "$credentials" of method "__construct()" is type-hinted "ar
>   ray", you should configure its value explicitly.

This is my service.yml file:

```
parameters:

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

imports:
    - { resource: "../src/Modules/Sales/Infrastructure/DependencyInjection/sales_module.yml" }
```

This is the code inside sales_module.yml:

```
services:
  module_sales.http.sales.repository:
    public: false
    class: App\Modules\Sales\Infrastructure\Persistence\Http\HttpSalesRepository
    arguments: ["%env(json:CREDENTIALS)%", "%env(json:TAGS)%"]
```

And this the HttpSalesRepository class

```
class HttpSalesRepository implements SalesRepository
{
    private $credentials;
    private $tags;

    public function __construct(array $credentials, array $tags)
    {
        $this->credentials = $credentials;
        $this->tags = $tags;
    }
    ...
 }
```

And this is the .env file:

```
###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
APP_ENV=dev
APP_SECRET=xxxxxx
###< symfony/framework-bundle ###

###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
DATABASE_URL=mysql://xxx:yyy@mysql:3306/db
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###

###> application/variables ###
CREDENTIALS='{"username":"email@test.com","password":"secretpass"}'
TAGS='["tag1","tag2","tag3"]'
###< application/variables ###
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can name the service arguments to explicitly match the parameter name to the value, instead of just having the argument list:

```
services:
  module_sales.http.sales.repository:
    public: false
    class: App\Modules\Sales\Infrastructure\Persistence\Http\HttpSalesRepository
    arguments: 
      $credentials: "%env(json:CREDENTIALS)%"
      $tags: "%env(json:TAGS)%"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is not the best option, but is a work arround while I find the final solution. If I define the service in config/services.yaml, the variables are passed to the services perfectly.

```
App\Modules\Sales\Infrastructure\Persistence\Http\HttpSalesRepository:
    public: false
    arguments: ["%env(json:AMAZON_AFFILIATES_CREDENTIALS)%", "%env(json:AMAZON_AFFILIATES_TAGS)%"]
```

Any other solution will be welcomed.